# TastyPie not responding to POSTs until it reaches the keepalive_timeout

Tags: nginx, tastypie, linode

This one has been baffling me for almost 24 hours now. For some reason on my linode server, tastypie isn't return a response to POSTs until it reaches the server's [keepalive_timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166066/django-tastypie-slow-post-response). It works perfectly for all GETs, PUTs, DELETEs and POSTs handled via override_urls (I'm using 0.9.11 for tastypie), but any standard POST (e.g. not handled override_urls) just sits there until the timeout limit is reached.

At first I thought it was a server config issue, but I'm now starting to suspect it's something to do with tastypie.

Relevant tastypie code:

```
class MissionResource(ModelResource):
    game = fields.ToOneField(GameResource, 'game')
    mission_bank = fields.ToOneField('goosechase.website.api.MissionBankResource', 'mission', null = True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Mission.objects.all()
        resource_name = "mission"
        always_return_data = True
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        excludes = ['hint_file_name']
        filtering = {
            "game" : ('exact'),
        }

        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication() 
        authorization = Authorization()

    # Added for testing various configs
    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/manually-handled-post/$" % 
                self._meta.resource_name, 
                self.wrap_view('generic_post')),
        ]

    # Test method for manually handled posts
    def manually_handled_post(self, request, **kwargs):
        self._meta.authentication.is_authenticated(request)
        self.is_authorized(request)

        return HttpResponse()
```

For some reason, doing a post to the "manually-handled-post/" endpoint works perfectly, as the response comes back in milliseconds, but a typical post doesn't return until it hits the server timeout. The testing code I did:

```
import requests
import json

# NORMAL POST ATTEMPT
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/api/web/mission/19/?format=json&api_key=API_KEY&username=USERNAME')

event = json.loads(response.content)

del event['id']
del event['resource_uri']

response = requests.post('http://www.example.com/api/web/mission/?format=json&api_key=API_KEY&username=USERNAME', data=json.dumps(event), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

# DELAY UNTIL SERVER keepalive_timeout IS REACHED, THEN <Response [201]> IS RETURNED

# OVERRIDEN POST ATTEMPT
response = requests.post('http://www.example.com/api/web/mission/manually-handled-post/?format=json&api_key=API_KEY&username=USERNAME', data=json.dumps({}), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
# INSTANTANEOUS RESPONSE WITH <Response [200]>
```

I checked that there's no save or obj_create hooks that are causing the delays. I've also verified that the same issues happen on multiple model resources.

Since overriden_urls work perfectly, I'm thinking that there's a bug in tastypie for POSTs, but I haven't found anything online and in the github issues.

Has anyone ran into this before and fixed it without reducing the keepalive_timeout to 0?

EDIT 1:
I started logging with timestamps to figure out where the slowdown occurred. Turns out there was no slowdown in the code, the delay was happening after the response was returned (e.g. return http.HttpCreated(location=location)). When I forced the POST to return a status code of 202 (via http.httpAccepted), it worked.

So now it seems the issue stems from **201 status codes on my server**. I have no idea why this would be happening, so if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm running into this exact same issue. Hope you get an answer! In the meantime I'm just getting rid of keepalive in my nginx conf.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing as well, upgrading nginx to a newer version (which supposedly solves it) wasn't an option for me at the time.